# I roll a die 4 times. In how many outcomes will each subsequent throw be greater that the previous one?

Tags: combinatorics, combinations

This is a question from GRE Entrance Exam. My first intuition was to make pairs. But that does not work apparently. What is the related concept? Can someone explain this to me?

Comment: Each string of values is equllay likely...how many are there and how many have the desired property?

Comment: 1234 1235 1236 1245 1246 1256 1345 1346 1356 1456 2345 2346 2356 2456 3456

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of fidling, I finally got to my answer which is explained as follows:

You need to do the fundamental principle of counting.

In Roll 1, we can get 1,2 or 3. If we get 3, there's only one possibility that the next three are 4,5,6.

If we get 2, then we can have 3 or 4. 3 will branch out to three possibilities and 4 will give one possibility. Counting like this, we will find out that there are 15 cases possible.

Comment: Yes - that works.  It is not a coincidence that ${6 \choose 4}=15$ as you want four distinct numbers from the six possibilities, in a particular order.  If you want a probability, you then need to divide by the total number of equally likely throws $6^4$

Comment: The whole point of a course on combinatorics is to learn how to count *without* using your fingers and toes like this.  You should not have needed to write out the possibilities.  If we had a $100$-sided die and we rolled it $20$ times you do **not** want to have to write out each branch individually and manually.  That would not be possible... even at writing an outcome every second would require a thousand times longer than the current age of the universe... and even if you could would be too prone to error.

Comment: On the other hand, using binomial coefficients (*which should have been introduced even at a highschool level, certainly by the time you take the GRE*) will get you the answer immediately.

Comment: Does anyone have any recommendations on a YouTube Playlist on Combatronics?